# Video Recording in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, video-capture

How can I record Videos in xamarin forms? I need a portable library plugin. I had already used Plugin.MediaManager and the recorded video with quality medium and compression low is having a size more than 500MB. Also if i try with a qulaity less than this, it will not play in iOS. Can anyone please help me to provide a solution on alternate plugins(cross platform) for recording video.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin?

Comment: @AkashKava Yes i tried, with that only above issue